# Updating packagelist

Tags: updates, package-management, muon-package-manager

The installation guide at kivy.org ([this one](http://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-linux.html#ubuntu-11-10-or-newer)) says that I have to update my packagelist using my package manager. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a terminal window and type

`sudo apt-get update`